# Debian LACP bond not working well?

Tags: debian, cisco, lacp, etherchannel

I am configured ifenslave LACP on my Debian 8.5. Two ports connected to a Cisco SLM2024 switch. 
If I disconnect 1 link, everything is ok, the another link working. But when I reconnect the 1st link, I can't ping the server, the network does not work. When I give *ifdown bond0* and *ifup bond0*, the network working again. It is normal? If not, what is the solution?

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.1.8
gateway 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves eth0 eth1
```

/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bonding mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1
```

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
Active Aggregator Info:
        Aggregator ID: 7
        Number of ports: 1
        Actor Key: 17
        Partner Key: 1
        Partner Mac Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 1c:98:ec:0e:4a:ac
Aggregator ID: 7
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 1c:98:ec:0e:4a:ad
Aggregator ID: 8
Slave queue ID: 0
```